# Password complexity policy

Tags: password, pam

System: Ubuntu 18.04

I've set up ubuntu with freeradius and am using the built in user authentication to authenticate logins.

I'm now trying to set up a simple way for the users to change their passwords and I'm using the ssh-auth-keys one command option via the passwd command, like so:

```
command="passwd" ssh-ed25519 public-key
```

However I'm having problems setting the password quality to what I want. For example I can't set the password to "trombon", it says that it's too simple.

I've tried adjusting the password complexity via libpam-pwquality but have not managed to figure it out, I'm pretty sure I'm missing something, as I understand it the only real hard constraint on password complexity is that it needs to be 6 characters minimum or is this incorrect?

Here is my `/etc/pam.d/common-password`:

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-password - password-related modules common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of modules that define the services to be
# used to change user passwords.  The default is pam_unix.

# Explanation of pam_unix options:
#
# The "sha512" option enables salted SHA512 passwords.  Without this option,
# the default is Unix crypt.  Prior releases used the option "md5".
#
# The "obscure" option replaces the old `OBSCURE_CHECKS_ENAB' option in
# login.defs.
#
# See the pam_unix manpage for other options.

# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
password        requisite                       pam_pwquality.so retry=3 dcredit=10 dictcheck=0 difok=0 lcredit=10 minlen=5 ocredit=10 ucredit=10
password        [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
password        requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
password        required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

Here is my `/etc/security/pwquality.conf`

```
# Configuration for systemwide password quality limits
# Defaults:
#
# Number of characters in the new password that must not be present in the
# old password.
difok = 0
#
# Minimum acceptable size for the new password (plus one if
# credits are not disabled which is the default). (See pam_cracklib manual.)
# Cannot be set to lower value than 6.
minlen = 6
#
# The maximum credit for having digits in the new password. If less than 0
# it is the minimum number of digits in the new password.
# Configuration for systemwide password quality limits
# Defaults:
#
# Number of characters in the new password that must not be present in the
# old password.
difok = 0
#
# Minimum acceptable size for the new password (plus one if
# credits are not disabled which is the default). (See pam_cracklib manual.)
# Cannot be set to lower value than 6.
minlen = 6
#
# The maximum credit for having digits in the new password. If less than 0
# it is the minimum number of digits in the new password.
dcredit = 10
#
# The maximum credit for having uppercase characters in the new password.
# If less than 0 it is the minimum number of uppercase characters in the new
# password.
ucredit = 10
#
# The maximum credit for having lowercase characters in the new password.
# If less than 0 it is the minimum number of lowercase characters in the new
# password.
lcredit = 10
#
# The maximum credit for having other characters in the new password.
# If less than 0 it is the minimum number of other characters in the new
# password.
ocredit = 10
#
# The minimum number of required classes of characters for the new
# password (digits, uppercase, lowercase, others).
minclass = 0
#
# The maximum number of allowed consecutive same characters in the new password.
# The check is disabled if the value is 0.
maxrepeat = 0
#
# The maximum number of allowed consecutive characters of the same class in the
# new password.
# The check is disabled if the value is 0.
maxclassrepeat = 0
#
# Whether to check for the words from the passwd entry GECOS string of the user.
# The check is enabled if the value is not 0.
gecoscheck = 0
#
# Whether to check for the words from the cracklib dictionary.
# The check is enabled if the value is not 0.
dictcheck = 0
#
# Whether to check if it contains the user name in some form.
# The check is enabled if the value is not 0.
usercheck = 1
#
# Whether the check is enforced by the PAM module and possibly other
# applications.
# The new password is rejected if it fails the check and the value is not 0.
enforcing = 1
#
# Path to the cracklib dictionaries. Default is to use the cracklib default.
# dictpath =
```

There are no other .conf files in the `/etc/security` folder which should interfere with the configuration of the `pwquality.conf` file.